# Using <google-chart> with Angular2

Tags: web-component, angular

I'm unable to get the web-component `<google-chart>` working in Angular2. If I add this:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/google-chart/google-chart.html">
<google-chart>details omitted</google-chart>
```

to the Quickstart `index.html` the chart fails to draw. If I comment out all the Angular 2 related stuff then the chart draws.

I get an unhelpful error that

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" in
>   zones.

I played around with this using the gulp-based ToDo app found on **Reddit** and found that if I comment out `zones.js` then the ToDo elements and chart draw, but the form and ToDo list fail to communicate. Putting `zones.js` back in, the ToDo app works but the chart doesn't draw. So it appears to be related to how Angular 2 uses zones.

Am I doing this wrong, or is this an Angular2 bug?

Comment: Chart components of PrimeNG can help. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/piechart

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing similar issue when using the  polymer element in an Angular 2 App. I finally fixed it by using the new binding mechanisms in Angular 2. The specific change is present [in this commit](https://github.com/tkhemani/Angular-2.0-app-using-polymer-elements-web-component/commit/af54e300f5a4b8704e74d2830d8965562888f32d). Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like you are binding click and content to the component. I'm not to the point of wanting to do that -- I can't even get the google-chart component to load.

Comment: I cloned your project and ran it. I had compile errors (es5build.js couldn't be found for some modules) but enough built that the page loaded. The "outside" button drew and worked, but the "inside" button did not show up. I then pasted the google-chart component into your index.html right after the "outside" component. I got version conflicts installing google-chart with bower and chose all the latest versions. After that, not even the "outside" component would draw.

I wonder if newer versions of webcomponents, polymer, etc., don't work with how Angular2 is using zones?